# I would like to return middle third of an array a

Tags: java, oop

Write the method `middle()` that takes an array `int[] a` and returns a new array holding the middle third of `a`. Assume that the length of `a` is multiple of 3. Eg: `middle({1,2,3,4,5,6})` should return  `{3,4}` and `middle({40,50,60,70,80,90}` should `{60,70}`.

```
public class middle {
   public static int[] middle(int[] a) {
      int newLen = a.length/3;
      int[] mid = new int[newLen];
      for (int i = 0; i < mid.length; i++) {
         mid[i] = a[newLen+i]; 
      }
      return mid; 
   }
}
```

When I try testing the above code it is not returning middle integers. 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: so what is being returned?  How are you calling this code?

Comment: What is being returned instead? The screenshot only shows that it is returning an array of integers but you're not showing what is inside the array. Looking at your code I don't see any obvious problems.

Comment: You're code is working fine, it's the BlueJ IDE you're using that's confusing. It is indeed returning the middle integers Object, which is of type `int[]`. I don't know how BlueJ works, but try placing this code *before* the line `return mid;`: `for(int i=0; i<mid.length;++i){ System.out.print(mid[i] + " "); }`, then you should be able to see the integers and then fix the output.

Comment: The code worked fine after placing the system.out.print code before return mid. Cheers guys.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check this code and read the comments carefully to understand

```
    int[] a = { 40, 50, 60, 70, 80};
    int newLen = (a.length- 1) / 2;

    int mid[];
    if (a.length % 2 == 0) {// checking for even number
        mid = new int[2];// if even number there must be two middle number

        mid[0] = a[newLen]; // taking first middle number
        newLen++;
        mid[1] = a[newLen]; // taking second middle number
    } else {// for odd number
        mid = new int[1];// one middle number
        mid[0] = a[newLen];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mid.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(mid[i] + " ");

    }
```

To make it a method

```
public static int[] middle(int[] a) {
    int newLen = (a.length- 1) / 2;

    int mid[];
    if (a.length % 2 == 0) {// checking for even number
        mid = new int[2];// if even number there must be two middle number

        mid[0] = a[newLen]; // taking first middle number
        newLen++;
        mid[1] = a[newLen]; // taking second middle number
    } else {// for odd number
        mid = new int[1];// one middle number
        mid[0] = a[newLen];
    }
  return mid; 
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP already posted working code. And this code doesn't work since you're supposed to return the middle third of the array, not the middle one or two numbers.